# How to manage GPG keychain in dockerized app?

Tags: ruby, docker, keychain, gnupg

I'm working on a dockerized Ruby on Rails app that has a worker that is responsible for decrypting a series of files before loading them into our database.

Because the gpg keychain is not guaranteed to contain the private key between deploys, the worker must download the private key and import it each time.

```
require 'gpgme'

def setup_gpg
  private_key = Tempfile.new(PRIVATE_KEY).binmode

  s3_client.get_object(bucket: config[:bucket],
                       key: PRIVATE_KEY,
                       response_target: private_key)

  GPGME::Key.import(private_key)
end

def decrypt_file(enc_file)
  decrypted_filename = enc_file.path.sub('.gpg', '.csv')

  File.open(enc_file) do |encrypted_file|
    File.open(decrypted_filename, 'w+') do |decrypted_file|
      crypto = GPGME::Crypto.new
      crypto.decrypt(encrypted_file,
                     output: decrypted_file,
                     password: config[:passphrase])
      return decrypted_file
    end
  end    
end
```

I'm using the [GPGME gem](https://github.com/ueno/ruby-gpgme) to interact with the gpg binary from ruby.

The problems with this approach:

- The private key lives in an S3 bucket
- The private key has to be downloaded and imported every time the job runs

We could DRY this process up a bit by checking if the key is already in the keychain, but I'd like to explore eliminating this step altogether.

Is there is a best practice for how to maintain the gpg keychain for a dockerized app? What options do I have for eliminating the need to store the key in S3 without committing the key to source control?